# Depuis quand et pourquoi utilise-t-on la formule : " année d'âge " ?

Tags: expressions, histoire

On dit souvent d'un Whiskey qu'il a par exemple: "15 ans d'âge"
Cela ressemble beaucoup à un pléonasme, car on ne peut pas avoir "15 ans d'autre chose".

S'il semble logique qu'une distance puisse nécessiter des précisions du type : " 5 mètres de long ou de large", il est plus compliqué de comprendre pourquoi l'on qualifie une durée par ce qu'elle est déjà.

Depuis quand et pourquoi utilise-t-on cette formule?

Comment: On peut avoir 15 ans de prison par exemple.

Comment: @Fréfré oui parce que dans ce cas-là "prison" ajoute une idée de contexte utile. Mais avoir des "années d'âge" équivaudrait plutôt à dire "il a fait 15 ans de la prison carcérale"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On parle probablement d'années d'âge pour les alcools forts, pour préciser qu'il s'agit de l'âge de la boisson à l'issue de la période de maturation (la durée passée en fût de chêne) et pas de l'âge absolu de la boisson elle-même.

C'est d'autant vrai que quand la boisson est le résultat d'un assemblage, c'est l'âge du composant le plus jeune qui est pris en compte.

Une fois mis en bouteille, on ne continue pas à comptabiliser les années puisqu'il n'y a quasiment plus de maturation.

Avec les vins, c'est différent car la maturation continue en bouteille. On ne parle d'ailleurs pas tellement d'un vin de x ans d'âge mais plutôt de millésime.

On parlait déjà d'années d'âge au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle, comme le montre l'extrait suivant:

[image]

V.-F. Lebeuf, *Calendrier des vins*, 1862.

Ont trouve de tous temps, des occurrences de *ans d'âge* où cette forme sert simplement à renforcer la phrase. On ne reproche d'ailleurs pas à *Il est âgé de quinze ans* d'être un pléonasme.

La plus ancienne occurrence que le moteur de recherche de la BNF rapporte est la suivante (ancienne graphie *aage*) :

[image]

*ANCIENS STATVTS des Maistres Lapidaires, dressez sous le regne de Saint Louïs', qui setrouuent au plus ancien Registre du Chastelet, de l'an mil deux cens quatre-vingts-dix*, 1549.

*Ans d'âge* est aussi parfois présent simplement pour satisfaire une rime :

> Ainsi a fait ce vertueux Seigneur,
> Lequel chargé de quatre-vingts ans d'âge,
> Plein toutefois d'un valeureux courage,
> Pour s'honorer d'un glorieux trespas

Ronsard, *Épitaphes de sujets divers*, 1604<sup>1</sup>

> Un myosotis clamait :
> Non je n'oublierai jamais,
> Quand je vivrais cent ans d'âge,
> Mille ans et même davantage.

Georges Brassens, Le discours des fleurs.

Comment: donc âge doit être considéré comme un synonyme de vieillissement ou maturation?

Comment: Oui, le nombre d'années passées en fût, comme les années de prison évoquées plus haut, ou les années d'étude, par exemple : neuf ans de médecine.